# Run Raspbian from RAM to improve responsiveness and stability

Tags: raspbian

I need help to run Raspbian on RAM.

I need to this in order to make the Pi powerfault safe. I want to be able to remove power to the Pi without problem.

I need to be able to remove the SD card after the system has booted. I stripped down a netinstalled Raspbian but now I can't find how to boot it from RAM.

I have tried to modify `cmdline.txt` but without result.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the SD card? The RAM will require a constant power supply as well...

Comment: I would direct you towards [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460091/embedded-file-system-and-power-off) first, and then consider a small Lithium Ion battery momentary backup solution with a shutdown trigger using the GPIO pins.  The RAM on the Pi is volatile (clears on power off) so that will not actually give you what you are wanting.

Comment: I can point you to https://www.embeddedarm.com/about/resource/preventing-filesystem-corruption-in-embedded-linux http://www.tinycorelinux.net/ (not sure about the Pi 4 for tiny core) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85524/how-do-i-make-the-os-reset-itself-every-time-it-boots-up/85569#85569 and http://www.enerco.si/content/overlay-filesystem-raspi One gent on the forum had used buildroot to make a r/o system but I cannot find the link.  Leave the SD card in - you need it to boot again after power off / on!