# debian PXE server don't boot twice

Tags: boot-issues, debian

I'm planning to do a Debian server which can deliver picore pxe to RPI 3/3+.

I have dnsmasq which gives a correct IP in the range and will provide the correct tftpboot option with the "Raspberry Pi Boot" given by a tag based on the mac address (3 first hex  b8:27:eb:*:*:*).

The first time, the rpi boots quite well (2nd try due to lack of traffic on my VLAN).
But after the first boot, I have to change my DHCP range to get another IP address. Without that change the Pi won't boot.

I've read that it may come from the GUID which says it already got the pxe boot and won't provide it twice.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to guess what the problem could be with the information you provide. Often I find it is the emulation of old style networking through *systemd*. *systemd* cannot 100 % emulate that old networking, particular with a complex setup like net booting, so you will find strange side effects. So I prefer to use *systemd* direct to realize net booting from a Raspberry Pi as master. You can look at an accepted solution at [Netbooting multiple “workers” RPi from a “master” RPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87361/79866).

Comment: Hi,the master is not an RPI 3 but an DEBIAN machine and I use the same pxe/tftp server as your solution but my problem is that he refuse to give the tftp directories if he already give it to this ip and mac. 
If I change the ip range to a new one, he give the tftp files without problems. But I want to know if there is a way to flush the GUID or the mac/ip combination.

Comment: EDIT : I've put the bootcode.bin in an SD and it works. Is it due to lack of trafic ?

Comment: @Thanatheos The bootcode.bi wasn't on a SD Card? Where was it? What GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) do you mean? Where do you want to flush it? Why? For what is the mac/ip combination good? What traffic do you mean?

Comment: the bootcode.bin is download from tftp. dnsmasq (and other pxe service) provide a list of matching ip/mac to keep the same ip for the same device. 
I guess it's a file that I could delete or something else.
For the traffic, I've often read that the pxe won't works if there are not a lot of traffic on the networks.