# Netboot PXE and usage extremly slow

Tags: networking, boot, raspbian-stretch, boot-issues

I tried to use the netboot feature of the RPi3 and booted via network. Therefore I used dnsmasq of pihole, tftpd-hpa and NFS on another Rpi3. I want to use the RPi headless. The Boot takes up to 30minutes and the ssh logon took more than 5 minutes. I checked the average loads and they had values greater than 10 but the cpu-usage is lower than 20%. The original image is much faster and there is no lack. How to analyze the problem better? I can’t imagine that’s normal.

Answer (score 1):

What model exactly do you use from the RPi3 family? Only model **3B+** is optimized for PXE boot. It may be possible also for model **3A+** because it is a stripped down *3B+* but I don't know. So if you use model **3B** it may be one reason for your problems.

Then with **dnsmasq**, **pihole**, **tftpd-hpa** and **NFS** there are some sophisticated applications that must be made to play together. In particular **pihole** and **tftpd-hpa** are not needed and complicate things unnecessary. A tftp server is already provided by *dnsmasq*.

How to setup a proper booting PXE only with **dnsmasq** and **nfs-kernel-server** you can find at [Netbooting multiple "workers" RPi from a "master" RPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87361/79866). You may give it at try.

Answer (score -1):

I've not done PXE boot with an RPi, but with x86 PXE, it is definitely slower than an RPi.

You didn't mention...Is the RPi WiFi or hardwired?

Comment: PXE boot can only be used on wired connections.

Comment: Doh...I know that. Not sure why I thought it was an important (albeit stupid) question to ask at the time.