# Network boot multiple Raspberry Pis

Tags: networking, boot, ethernet

I am looking into SD cardless network boot options for a bunch of RPis. I would like them to all boot from one server, which should provide either of two images to the raspberry, as well as an individual host name for identification.

The raspberries don't need to save any persistent data, only temporary log files for debugging.

What options are there to specify which raspberry gets which disk image (and preferably assign an individual host name)

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/piserver/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbooting multiple "workers" RPi from a "master" RPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87262/netbooting-multiple-workers-rpi-from-a-master-rpi)

Comment: I tried now the piserver software, and while I got them to appear as clients, I can't manage to get them to appear on the network anywhere else afterwards, and I can't find any resource how to debug the system