# Booting from network and installing os

Tags: networking, operating-systems

Is it possible to download any suitable os from network and install it same way like using pxe boot on pc?

Update:
Reason for that is saving time when installin multiple Raspberries without need every time made a new sd-card if some program is changed etc.

Comment: What sort of research did you do on this?

Comment: Some. Nothing about _installing_ os from network. I want install os from network to sd-card or harddisk connected to this rpi.

Comment: Do you really want to use PXE boot? Then first of all you have to setup a netboot environment. Does the RasPi can boot from your network to load the installation program for the SD Card?

Comment: What scenario are you thinking of where it'd be easier to network boot (including setting up a tftp server with the image, etc.) than to just swap out the SD card? Some additional details would be helpful.

Comment: I updated question.

Comment: If you're looking to make changes to multiple installs, have you looked at tools like puppet? E.g., http://frederickvandenbosch.be/?p=1843

Comment: Maybe, if puppet-agent rpi can be moved away and it can be still work as regular installed rpi.

Answer (score 2):

I see mainly two possibilities for your needs. You can setup a debian repository. Then you only need an initial SD Card installation that can be updated with **apt** from your own repository. How to do it you may have a look at [Debian Repository Setup](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup).

You can setup a net booting infrastructure. This is more flexible than an repository because you can load complete different operating systems to the RasPi that may run from the network without a SD Card. Or you can run an installer program from the network that flashes an image to the SD Card and reboot to the SD Card. But net booting is limited to wired network connections. How to install a net boot infrastructure using Raspberry Pis you can look at [Netbooting multiple “workers” RPi from a “master” RPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87361/79866).